# Springboot 3.0 cannot config CORS

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I try to configure CORS policy, but it doesn't work.
When i send a request i recieve headers like this:

```
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2023 10:33:36 GMT
```

with no allow-origins. How can i fix this problem?

Spring security config code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class JWTSecurityConfig {
    //here is jwt setting
...
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter, ServerProperties serverProperties) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
        http.anonymous();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable();

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        });

        if (serverProperties.getSsl() != null && serverProperties.getSsl().isEnabled()) {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        } else {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
        }

        http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/attributes/questions", "/attr-values/recent-values", "/attr-values/history").hasAuthority("default-roles-ai-solutions").requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/attr-values/save-attr-values").hasAuthority("default-roles-ai-solutions").anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

dependencies in pom.xml

- spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.0
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 3.0.0
- spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:3.0.0

When i enable cors like this:

> http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());

i recieve if request isn't correct:

```
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2023 12:46:25 GMT
```

if it's correct request:

```
Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Allow: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS
< Accept-Patch:
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2023 13:28:44 GMT
```

part with jwt config

```
   public interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
        // This is a converter for roles as embedded in the JWT by a Keycloak server
        // Roles are taken from both realm_access.roles & resource_access.{client}.roles

        return jwt -> {
            final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
            final var realmRoles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            final var resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("resource_access", Map.of());
            // We assume here you have "employee-service" (as in the tutorial referenced in the question) and "other-client" clients configured with "client roles" mapper in Keycloak
            final var confidentialClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault("employee-service", Map.of());
            final var confidentialClientRoles = (Collection<String>) confidentialClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());
            final var publicClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault("other-client", Map.of());
            final var publicClientRoles = (Collection<String>) publicClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            final var realmScopes = Arrays.asList(((String) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("scope", "")).split(" "));
            realmScopes.replaceAll(scope -> "SCOPE_" + scope);
            final var grantedAuthorityScopes = (Collection<String>) realmScopes;
            return Stream.concat(realmRoles.stream(), Stream.concat(confidentialClientRoles.stream(), Stream.concat(publicClientRoles.stream(), grantedAuthorityScopes.stream()))).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
        };
    }

    public interface Jwt2AuthenticationConverter extends Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
    }

    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter) {
        return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
    }
```

I expect to recieve:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: You disable CORS but still expect the headers?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. I tried to enable cors in diffrent ways. I described one of them.

Comment: CORS should appear much earlier (at least before any authentication filter) in your filter chain. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html

Comment: The order of configuring doesn't matter.

Comment: @M.Deinum Really? I haven't dug into the code, but I find that surprising. Does Spring somehow know in which order the different filters should be combined?

Comment: Spring Security filters have a pre-defined order, how you configure them doesn't matter.

Comment: @M.Deinum Interesting. But how do you reconcile that with what my link says? _CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies (i.e. the `JSESSIONID`). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request will determine the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and reject it._ Why would the Spring documentation warn users about that?

Comment: You are linking to the Reactive documentation **not** the servlet documentation. While similar different beast to configure and not comparable. WHat applies to one doesn't (always) apply to others. To make matters worse there is also CORS support in regular Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see. Quite confusing. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4):

I think the error is at line: `http.csrf().disable().cors().disable();`. You should use istead `http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());` and the method `corsConfigurationSource` is not a `@Bean`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class JWTSecurityConfig {
    
...
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter, ServerProperties serverProperties) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
        http.anonymous();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


        http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        });

        if (serverProperties.getSsl() != null && serverProperties.getSsl().isEnabled()) {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        } else {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
        }

        http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/attributes/questions", "/attr-values/recent-values", "/attr-values/history").hasAuthority("default-roles-ai-solutions").requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/attr-values/save-attr-values").hasAuthority("default-roles-ai-solutions").anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }

    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

You should replace  `configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"))` with `configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*")`.

```
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");

        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        
        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
```

Comment: The result hasn't changed.

Comment: please update for spring 3.1 now that the some of the methods used here are already deprecated for removal

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what @David said in his edited answer, the trick for me was to allow OPTIONS requests as well, so I added this line

```
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
```

It wasn't needed before in Spring boot 2.x

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using following code onn spring boot 3

```
    @Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Requestor-Type","Content-Type"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}




 return httpSecurity
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()

            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Both @david-pérez-cabrera and @m-denium are right

Replace `cors().disable()` with `configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())`.

### Your authentication converter is not picked

Spring-boot expects a `Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>` bean when you provide a `Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>`, and guess what?, `AbstractAuthenticationToken` does not extend `AbstractAuthenticationToken`...

The 403 you get with `http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());` is probably not a CORS error.

Given your conf, my guess (we don't have the details of the requests you attempt) is that you are missing the `default-roles-ai-solutions` authority when issuing either:

- a GET request to one of "/attributes/questions", "/attr-values/recent-values", "/attr-values/history"
- a POST request to "/attr-values/save-attr-values"

Two options:

- correctly copy from my code, including this part: `oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(...)`
- change your `Jwt2AuthenticationConverter` interface definition from `extends Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>` to `extends Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken>`

Comment: I added information about my problem. When i send correct reuqest i recieve the same headers. I have authentication converter. I removed part of code it took a lot of space.

Comment: If we don't have all of your security conf, in the state where you face the problem, there are very little chance we solve it.

Comment: Sorry. I added part with jwt configuration. When I first tried this, stackoverflow complained that there was too much code.

Comment: edited my answer because of new info

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Spring Boot 3.x version, you can use it as follows.

**you must delete the line where you disabled cors**

```
http.cors().disable();
```

**Solution 1**

You just should define a class like this.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        CorsRegistration corsRegistration = registry.addMapping("/**");
        corsRegistration.allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
        corsRegistration.allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Requestor-Type", "Content-Type");
        corsRegistration.exposedHeaders("Content-Disposition"); // file download filename header

        String[] allowedOriginPatternsArray = Stream.of("your_allowed_origin_pattern")
                .map(String::trim)
                .filter(StringUtil::isNotEmpty)
                .toArray(String[]::new);

        corsRegistration.allowedOriginPatterns(allowedOriginPatternsArray);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Then you should add the following line to the SecurityFilterChain bean and give the corsConfigurationSource bean defined below to the configurationSource method.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   ...
    http.cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));
   ...
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Requestor-Type", "Content-Type"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```